# Debugging HashMap shows a recursive entrySet? What is it?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using an `HashMap<String,Serializable>` and while debugging I see the following recursively. What does that mean? Why is it so?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`HashMap$EntrySet` is a inner class, it has an explicit reference called `this$0` to the `HashMap`. And the `HashMap` has a field `private transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet` which refers to it. So, just usual cyclic references.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oh, just a typo. Thanks

Comment: What you said was true of HashSet as well as it wraps a HashMap. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ha, it's true, but confused the answer anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The `HashMap` instance has a field `entrySet` with the type `HashMap$EntrySet`. Since the `EntrySet` class is an inner class of `HashMap`, it has an implicit reference to the containing instance (`this$0`).

This is normal and required for the `EntrySet` instance to access the containing `HashMap` instance.